# python 3 int() problems

Tags: python, int

```
nextt[0:1] = "*2"

rds = int(nextt[0:1].replace("*",""))
```

And there is problem, it says:`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`

I just need to delete "*" from string and convert it to int.

Comment: What type is `nextt` to allow for string slice assignment here? Or are you merely illustrating what you *think* `nextt` contains after slicing?

Answer (score 4):

You are slicing just **one** character:

```
>>> '*2foo'[0:1]
'*'
```

Replacing the `*` gives you an empty string. Perhaps you wanted to slice two characters?

```
>>> '*2foo'[:2]
'*2'
```

If you are slicing anyway, just pick the digit character *without* the `*`:

```
int(nextt[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 int('*2'.replace('*', ''))
```

1. `'*2'.replace('*', '')` this replaces * with empty string and results in '2'
2. Now you cast it to int.